# Laravel Sentinel foreign key

Tags: laravel, sentinel

I'm trying to register a person with Sentinel and Laravel 5. `

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    $credentials = [
        'email'    => 'john.doe@example.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'client_id' =>1,
    ];

    $user = Sentinel::register($credentials);
});`
```

I'm getting this response

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a
 child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbmenubook`.`users`, CONSTRAINT 
`fk_users_me_clients1` FOREIGN 
KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `me_clients` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION 
ON UPDATE NO ACTION) (SQL: insert into `users` 
(`email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (john.doe@example.com,
y2016-02-23 
16:02:31fQMyg1raDBf/dNrQGQMe.LDxEHO5yQCA.J5cbZKmyuLKLYzzUIra, 
2016-02-23 
16:02:31, ?))
```

Now I'm trying to add the client_id which gives me this error. But it seems like the client_id isn't being sent. I'm guessing it has something to do with the model and the fillable array but this seems to be oke

User Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

User table

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `permissions` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `client_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `last_login` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ipad_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=79 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Doesn anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the similar issue.

Please check your /config/sentinel.cartalyst.php config file (if you published it).

I found there that user model Sentinel was it's default Eloquent model, which haven't had necessary attributes.

I've created my model, extended default Sentinel Eloquent model and implementing it's interfaces, added there new array of fillable fields and it worked.

I'm not sure that this is the best and right solution, but there's no answers and I hope this solution can help you.